# How to select values that are not in the list using MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Currently i want some records that are not present in one field  ie,I want to select the records in the position that are not present in immediate parent .

This is my table structure

[image]

i want the result as

> 1.1.1 , 1.2.1 , 1.3.1

I tried using (not in)  syntax bu it throws error . Any help is appreciable

Comment: what error is shows? and can you explain more

Comment: It is not clear what exactly you are trying to do...can you be more specific

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want all records whose positions are not the immediate parent of some other record.  We can try using a self-anti-join:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable t1
LEFT JOIN yourTable t2
    ON t1.position = t2.immediate_parent
WHERE t2.position IS NULL;
```

Another way to phrase this is using an `EXISTS` clause:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable t2 WHERE t2.immediate_parent = t1.position);
```

Comment: In other words, the 'leaves' or 'leaf nodes'

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM tableA A
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM tableA AA
        WHERE A.position = AA.immediate_parent
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly you need records that have level 2 and more.

```
SELECT T1.* FROM 
yourTable T1
INNER JOIN yourTable T2 on T2.immediate_parent=T1.position
INNER JOIN yourTable T3 on T3.immediate_parent=T2.position
```

in your particular sample it can be accomplish also by check how many dots are there ;-)